# syntax error near unexpected token `<' from Applescript to Python

Tags: python, html, runtime, applescript

I am using the following command to pass a string to python from Applescript

String mytext contains the HTML body of an email starting with <...

**Applescript**

```
display dialog (do shell script "/Users/mymac/Documents/'Microsoft User Data'/'Outlook Script Menu Items'/ test.py" & mytext)
```

**Python**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys
import string

def main():
    print sys.argv[1:]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

How can I rectify this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to pass the HTML as an argument to the Python script. Instead, do something like:

```
display dialog (do shell script "/Users/mymac/Documents/'Microsoft User Data'/'Outlook Script Menu Items'/ test.py < webpage.html")
```

---

```
print sys.stdin.read()
```

Comment: how do I assign mytext to webpage.html?

Comment: by writing it to a file called my "webpage.html"?? Preferable in "tempfile" in your "tempdir"?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are executing a shell script ... by constructing a long line of text. 
   "/Users/mymac/Documents/'Microsoft User Data'/'Outlook Script Menu Items'/ test.py" & " ... ")

but the "<" sign and the ">" sign have a special meaning for the shell.